# how to change to a different globalization with a resources file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, localization, visual-studio-2017, globalization

**How do I get localization to extract values from the correct resx file?**

I've got two files, one for English, and the other for Czech:

[image]

To quickly preview their contents:

[image]

I am attempting to switch the *culture/localization*. I do believe that the culture is being set; however, it is still not using the `cs-CZ` file:

```
                                        Dim value = InnerNode.InnerText
                    Dim cultures() As String = {"cs-CZ"}
                    Dim rnd As New Random()
                    Dim cultureNdx As Integer = rnd.Next(0, cultures.Length)
                    Dim originalCulture As CultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture

                    Dim newCulture As New CultureInfo(cultures(cultureNdx))
                        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture

                    Dim currentLanguageValue = My.Resources.GlobalStrings.ResourceManager.GetString(value)
```

**We know that the current culture is indeed *cs-CZ*:**

[image]

We see that the value of `currentLanguageValue` should have been `Mandl`:

[image]

but it was `Almond` - this means it was not recognizing the GlobalStrings.cs-CZ.resx file at all.

**What am I doing wrong, how do I get it to recognize the czech resources file?**

Comment: Can you retrieve the expected value if you use the overload of `GetString` that takes a CultureInfo?

Comment: also tried this ```Dim culture = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.GetValues("culture").ToString```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set CultureInfo at entry point of your application (Sub Main or constructor of main Form, or Application.Startup event). I am afraid that setting CultureInfo anywhere else during runtime will have no effect on loading right resources.